# Error while connecting spark and cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

**What I'm doing:**

- Trying to connect Spark and Cassandra to retrieve data stored at cassandra tables from spark.

**What steps have I followed:**

- Download **cassandra 2.1.12** and **spark 1.4.1**.
- Built spark with `sudo build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean packag` and `sbt/sbt clean assembly`
- Stored some data into cassandra.
- Downloaded these jars into `spark/lib`:

[cassandra-driver-core2.1.1.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.1)  and [spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-1.4.1.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/1.4.17)

Added the jar file paths to `conf/spark-defaults.conf` like

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath \
                            ~/path/to/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-1.4.1.jar:\
                            ~/path/to/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.1.jar
```

**How am I running the shell:**

After running `./bin/cassandra`, I run spark like-

`sudo ./bin/pyspark`

and also tried with `sudo ./bin/spark-shell`

**What query am I making**

```
sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
               .options(table="users", keyspace="test")\
               .load()\
               .show()
```

**The problem:**

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:\
                    scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
```

But `org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra` is present in the spark-cassandra-connecter.jar that I downloaded.

Here is the full [Log Trace](http://justpaste.it/qs3t)

**What have I tried:**

- I tried running with the option `--packages` and `--driver-class-path` and `--jars` options by adding the 2 jars.
- Tried downgrading scala to 2.1 and tried with the scala shell but still the same error.

**Questions I've been thinking about-**

1. Are the versions of cassandra, spark and scala that I'm using compatible with each other?
2. Am I using the correct version of the jar files?
3. Did I compile spark in the wrong way?
4. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I'm really new to spark and cassandra so I really need some advice! Been spending hours on this and probably it's something trivial.

Comment: My working spark dependency set looks like this, try it and let me know if it works:
spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.3.0-M2
spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10:1.3.0-M2
spark-core_2.10:1.3.0
spark-streaming_2.10:1.3.0
As a cassandra connector i use spring-data

Comment: @Damiano Do you have the same versions of cassandra, spark and scala as I do? I'm running python 2.7.6.

Comment: Connector 1.4 is compatible with Cassandra 2.1.5+ (see [Version Compatibility](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility)).

Answer (score 4):

A few notes

One you are building spark for 2.10 and using Spark Cassandra Connector libraries for 2.11. To build spark for 2.11 you need to use the `-Dscala-2.11` flag. This is most likely the main cause of your errors.

Next to actually include the connector in your project just including the core libs without the dependencies will not be enough. If you got past the first error you would most likely see other class not found errors from the missing deps.

This is why it's recommended to use the Spark Packages website and `--packages` flag. This will include a "fat-jar" which has all the required dependencies. See 
http://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

For Spark 1.4.1 and pyspark this would be

```
//Scala 2.10
$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.4.1-s_2.10
//Scala 2.11
$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.4.1-s_2.11
```

You should never have to manually download jars using the `--packages` method.

Do not use spark.driver.extraClassPath , it will only add the dependencies to the driver remote code will not be able to use the dependencies.

Comment: Just one question , I'm getting the results from cassandra but before I got the result and after I submitted the query, I got something  like `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll6452785661344203257.so: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll6452785661344203257.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
`. What does this error mean?

Comment: there is still no connector compatible with spark 1.6 right?

Comment: Connector 1.5 works with Spark 1.6, a 1.6 specific version can be built from master if you need it. (Hint use ./sbt/sbt assembly to get the `fat-jar`)